# UI5: sap.f.ShellBar vs. sap.tnt.ToolHeader

Tags: sapui5

I'm exploring the UI5 [Tool Header](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/tool-header/) UI component.

As far as I can see, there is an option to implement such UI component either with [`sap.f.ShellBar`](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.f.ShellBar/sample/sap.f.sample.ShellBar) or with [`sap.tnt.ToolHeader`](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.tnt.ToolHeader/sample/sap.tnt.sample.ToolHeaderFiori3). Since both UI elements look pretty similar, what's the difference?

Is `sap.f.ShellBar` just a newer/modern implementation of the functionality, provided by `sap.tnt.ToolHeader`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tool Header control is part of the `sap.tnt` library and this library "[...] targets the specific needs of the tools user group (typically developers and administrators)" ([taken from the UI5 documentation](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/d8374d578a4c4f9498f9f14a6672c8bb)). By contrast, the Shell Bar is part of the `sap.f` library with controls specialized for application-oriented UIs.

Further details and guidelines on these two specific controls can be found in the SAP Fiori design guidelines for the [Shell Bar](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/shell-bar/) or rather the [Tool Header](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/tool-header/).